# What is the maximum site collection limit for SharePoint 2019 Server Farm(On premise)

Tags: sharepoint-server, site-collection, administration, 2019, limitations

I am new in **Sharepoint 2019**, Just wanted to know sharepoint 2019 Server farm limits.

1. Maximum Site Collections limit per server farm
2. Maximum Sites Contain by a web application pool in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Check this documentation for full list of SharePoint 2019 limitations: [Software boundaries and limits for SharePoint Servers 2016 and 2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/software-boundaries-limits-2019)

You will find all the limitations related to no. of web applications, Application pools, content databases, site collections, etc.

Comment: How about Web application limits in there, it says
Web application 20 per farm Supported
We recommended limiting the number of web applications as much as possible. Create additional host named site collections where possible instead of adding web applications.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Site collection limits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/software-boundaries-limits-2019#site-collection-limits)
   [image]
2. The number of site collections you can have in a single web application depends on the capacity of your server infrastructure.

Comment: Thank you, Allen for your support, I am still confuse with webapplications limit and Site collection limit in a server farm.

Comment: You’ll need to elaborate on what part is confusing you so we can help.